# How to convert SQL to firestore query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-schema

I have a query statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers  WHERE (@ID IS NULL OR ID = @ID) AND (@Name IS NULL OR Name = @Name)
```

But I dont know to use it in firestore. Can you help me. Thanks you

Comment: Firestore has no equivalent of `OR` conditions in queries, at least not of the type you're using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
var cRef = db.collection("customers");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = cRef.where("id", "in", [NULL,"YOURID"]).where("name", "in", [NULL,"YOURNAME"]);
query.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: That's a query that works as an `AND` and not a `OR`, as the OP is looking for.